# How to use if statement to display taxonomy name if in the taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I'm using the code below to get the name and slug of a custom taxonomy and than in the loop I echo the taxonomy name but not every post is linked to this taxonomy and if the post is not linked to the taxonomy get the error

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

So I was wondering how do I use an if statement so if the post is not in the taxonomy than nothing happens. I tried wrapping the code below in a if(is_tax statement when I did that the custom taxonomy name didn't display on any of the posts.

```
<?php 
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'class-content' );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $class_name = $term->name; // this grabs the hyphenated name
            $class_slug = $term->slug; // this grabs the hyphenated slug
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'class-content' );
if(is_object($terms)){
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $class_name = $term->name; // this grabs the hyphenated name
            $class_slug = $term->slug; // this grabs the hyphenated slug
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, although I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' error for the entire page with that.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' error for the entire page

Comment: Thanks, that corrected the error but now when $class_name is echoed in the loop nothing shows up, where with my original code it showed up when the post was tied to that taxonomy but just gave me an error when the post wasn't tied to 'class-content' taxonomy.

Comment: Thank you, so I need to echo $class_name in the if and then echo that backout where I want it to be displayed.

Comment: @Greenhoe : Have you succeeded?

Comment: I think so, just double checking making sure it works for all scenarios.